# Default Segue to ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

Im relatively new to swift, treading my way slowly. 
Below is my code:

```
let defaultName = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let getTheme =  defaultName.integer(forKey: "theme") as Int
    if getTheme == 1{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "darkVC", sender: self)
    }else
        if getTheme == 2{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lightVC", sender: self)
        } else {
            //Do nothing
    }
}

@IBAction func theme_Selection(_ sender: UIButton) {
    defaultName.set(sender.tag, forKey: "theme")

}
```

Viewcontroller:
[image]

I'm attempting to save the user selection (Dark or Light) and segue to respective Viewcontroller, in my UserDefaults. Unfortunately, it does save the UserDefault and keeps coming back to this Viewcontroller for user selection.

I've tagged the buttons as 1 and 2 and grouped them in `@IBAction func theme_Selection`

Any ideas what am I missing here ? 
Thanks in advance to any solution.

Comment: What is `getVal`? By the way delete `as Int`, `integer(forKey` returns always `Int`.

Comment: delete app form simulator and reinstall, it will work.

Comment: @vadian Thanks, edited the correction. I deleted `as Int`. Should `defaultName.integer` be re-assigned?

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what your problem is. Can you rephrase your question a bit?

Comment: Unsuccessful :( still.

Comment: @ØyvindHauge After logging in, im attempting to save the user's choice of theme from the button selected. Despite running the code & re-running the app, it lands back to this viewcontroller, in other words doesnt remember user button selection

Comment: Ok, got it. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks to all folks here to assisted me. Answer by @ØyvindHauge explained it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to `performSegue` in `viewDidLoad`. The view hasn't been attached to the window yet. Try moving your implementation to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Genius. Works now. Makes complete sense. Thanks a lot.